# How add productionMode in shadowjar?

Tags: gradle, vaadin, shadowjar

In my Vaadin project I use gradle.

here my build.gradle:

```
plugins {
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.3.20"
    id ("com.github.johnrengelman.shadow") version "4.0.3"
    id ("com.devsoap.vaadin-flow") version "1.0"
    id ("org.gretty") version "2.3.1"
}

val kotlinVersion = "1.3.20" //by extra("1.3.20")
val jettyVersion = "9.4.14.v20181114"
val vaadinVersion = "12.0.4"

val shadowJar by tasks.getting(ShadowJar::class) {
    manifest.attributes["Main-Class"] = "myproject.Main.class"
    mergeServiceFiles()
}
```

To build project (to executable jar)  I use Gradle's pluggin : `shadowjar`.

```
gradlew shadowjar
```

Nice. It's work fine.

But I need to build project in product mode for Vaadin

```
vaadin{
    setProductionMode(true)
}
```

How I can do this by `shadowjar`?